# dynamic GridView with dynamic Number Of Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How I can create dynamic GridView with dynamic number of row When click on button

and put in one column DropDownList .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty brief, but if if i think i understand what you want to do, you could try this:

in the codebehind of your button

```
List<string> ThisIsYourList = new List<string>();
Gridview1.DataSource = ThisIsYourList;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

if you want to add a dropdownlist to every row, you need to add an itemtemplate to your gridview like this:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"/>
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
```

You add this itemtemplate anywhere between the  tags of your gridview.

Comment: Thanks but I need person who use my program to define the number of row in textbox and I well generate Grid for him contain five column 
and row with the number of row that he insert in textbox ?

Answer (score 0):

GridView is a databound control. It means that it shows what is in the datasource. To add a row, you need to add an item to the datasource and re-bind the gridview. You can't add rows to the gridview directly.